# How can I specify a generic type parameter in a Kotlin @Deprecated annotation?

Tags: kotlin

I want to rename a Kotlin type, leaving a deprecated typealias to allow existing code to compile.

```
typealias TestContext<F> = ContextBuilder<F>
```

---

```
@Deprecated("TestContext is now ContextBuilder", 
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("ContextBuilder<F>"))
```

leads to `TextContext<Unit>` being replaced with `ContextBuilder<F>`

```
@Deprecated("TestContext is now ContextBuilder", 
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("ContextBuilder"))
```

leads to `TextContext<Unit>` being replaced with `ContextBuilder`

How can I write the replaceWith expression so that IntelliJ replaces `TextContext<Unit>` with `ContextBuilder<Unit>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible now! The `ReplaceWith` intention saves generic type arguments from Kotlin plugin v1.3.40 on (see [change log](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#new-features-12)).